# making the code more robust (jquery)

Tags: jquery

please have a look at the entire code and if you copy and paste it in your html then should be working.

as you can see in the below code i have to create two set of code for every action (jquery,css) and what i am trying to achieve is that, i just need to have one set of code for all the actions below...

i am not worried too much about click event and actually i would like to have that two separate click event for the. `$("#button").click(function(){...}`, `$("#button1").click(function(){...}`

**Updated:**

html:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>yensdesign.com - How to create a stuning and smooth popup in jQuery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="general.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <div id="button">
            <input type="submit" value="button" /></div>
        <div id="button1">
            <input type="submit" value="button1" /></div>
    </center>
    <div id="popupContact">
        <a id="popupContactClose">x</a>
        <h1>
            Title of our cool popup, yay!</h1>
        <p id="contactArea">
            Here we have a simple but interesting sample of our new stuning and smooth popup. 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="popupContact1">
        <a id="popupContactClose1">x</a>
        <h1>
            one more, yay!</h1>
        <p id="contactArea1">
            Here we have a simple but interesting sample of our new stuning and smooth popup. 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="backgroundPopup">
    </div>
    <div id="backgroundPopup1">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**jquery:**

```
var popupStatus = 0;
var popupStatus1 = 0;

//loading popup with jQuery magic!
function loadPopup(){
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if(popupStatus==0){
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({"opacity": "0.7" });
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}

//loading popup with jQuery magic!
function loadPopup1() {
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if (popupStatus == 0) {
        $("#backgroundPopup1").css({ "opacity": "0.7" });
        $("#backgroundPopup1").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#popupContact1").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus1 = 1;
    }
} 

//disabling popup with jQuery magic!
function disablePopup(){
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if(popupStatus==1){
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}

//disabling popup with jQuery magic!
function disablePopup1(){
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if(popupStatus1==1){
        $("#backgroundPopup1").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#popupContact1").fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatus1 = 0;
    }
} 

//centering popup
function centerPopup(){
    //request data for centering
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
    var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();
    //centering
    $("#popupContact").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,
        "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
    });
    //only need force for IE6

    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });
}

//centering popup
function centerPopup1() {
    //request data for centering
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $("#popupContact1").height();
    var popupWidth = $("#popupContact1").width();
    //centering
    $("#popupContact1").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight / 2 - popupHeight / 2,
        "left": windowWidth / 2 - popupWidth / 2
    });
    //only need force for IE6

    $("#backgroundPopup1").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });

}

//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //LOADING POPUP
    //Click the button event!
    $("#button").click(function(){
        //centering with css
        centerPopup();
        //load popup
        loadPopup();
    });

    $("#button1").click(function () {
        //centering with css
        centerPopup1();
        //load popup
        loadPopup1();
    });

    //CLOSING POPUP
    //Click the x event!
    $("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
});
//Click the x event!
$("#popupContactClose1").click(function () {
    disablePopup1();
});

//Click out event!
    $("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
});

$("#backgroundPopup1").click(function () {
    disablePopup1();
});

    //Press Escape event!
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
            disablePopup();
        }
        if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus1==1){
            disablePopup1();
        }
    });

});
```

**css**

```
#backgroundPopup{
display:none;
position:fixed;
_position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/
height:100%;
width:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
background:#000000;
border:1px solid #cecece;
z-index:1;
}
#backgroundPopup1{
display:none;
position:fixed;
_position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/
height:100%;
width:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
background:#000000;
border:1px solid #cecece;
z-index:1;
}
#popupContact{
display:none;
position:fixed;
_position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/
height:384px;
width:408px;
background:#FFFFFF;
border:2px solid #cecece;
z-index:2;
padding:12px;
font-size:13px;
}
#popupContact1{
display:none;
position:fixed;
_position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/
height:384px;
width:408px;
background:#FFFFFF;
border:2px solid #cecece;
z-index:2;
padding:12px;
font-size:13px;
}
#popupContact h1{
text-align:left;
color:#6FA5FD;
font-size:22px;
font-weight:700;
border-bottom:1px dotted #D3D3D3;
padding-bottom:2px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}
#popupContact1 h1{
text-align:left;
color:#6FA5FD;
font-size:22px;
font-weight:700;
border-bottom:1px dotted #D3D3D3;
padding-bottom:2px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}
#popupContactClose{
font-size:14px;
line-height:14px;
right:6px;
top:4px;
position:absolute;
color:#6fa5fd;
font-weight:700;
display:block;
}
#popupContactClose1{
font-size:14px;
line-height:14px;
right:6px;
top:4px;
position:absolute;
color:#6fa5fd;
font-weight:700;
display:block;
}
#button{
text-align:center;
margin:100px;
}
#button1{
text-align:center;
margin:100px;
}
```

End update

I am following this [blog](http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/) and one thing got stuck me is, I have two links that I created in order for the two separate links to work, i have to add the same code twice in jquery and css...but i am thinking there should be a better way of doing that... duplicate code with just name diff.

i have added the core of the code so in order for my button1 to work , i have to add twice the same code as shown below with just name diff

```
    <div id="button"><input type="submit" value="Press me please!" /></div>
    <div id="button1"><input type="submit" value="Press one more time!" /></div>


   <div id="popupContact">
        <a id="popupContactClose">x</a>
        <h1>Title of our cool popup, yay!</h1>
        <p id="contactArea">
            Here we have a simple but interesting sample 
        </p>
    </div>
```

the source code of the jquery is:

```
$("#backgroundPopup1").css({
        "opacity": "0.7"
    });
    $("#backgroundPopup1").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#popupContact1").fadeIn("slow");
```

the .css

```
#popupContact  {
display:none;
position:fixed;
_position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/
height:384px;
width:408px;
background:#FFFFFF;
border:2px solid #cecece;
z-index:2;
padding:12px;
font-size:13px;
}
```

Comment: Something is missing from your jQuery... I don't see any code for the buttons.

Comment: I did not past the full code but u can have look at the link I have - blog link

Comment: Nothing wrong with linking but your question should be fully self-contained.  http://sscce.org

Comment: i have updated my question, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the jQuery code you provided, The only i improvement i would suggest is using chaining

```
$("#backgroundPopup1").css({ "opacity": "0.7"}).fadeIn("slow");
$("#popupContact1").fadeIn("slow");
```

For avoiding repeated code for binding same functionality for many elements, you may bind it only once like this

```
$(function(){
 
  $("#btnSave,#btnSaveMore").click(function(e){
    //do your stuff here
  });

});
```

This will be applied to 2 elements with id `btnSve` and `btnSaveMore`

**EDIT : As per the updated question.**

So you have duplicated code for 2 buttons. Let us rewrite it like this.

Let us make some changes to your HTML markup. We will give ID's to the buttons to identify which button is being clicked.

```
<input id="btn-1" type="submit" value="button" /></div>
<input id="btn-2" type="submit" value="button1" /></div>

<div id="popupContact1"></div>
<div id="popupContact2"></div>
<div id="backgroundPopup1"></div>
<div id="backgroundPopup2"></div>
```

Now lets go to the javascript,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
       var id=$(this).attr("id").split("-")[1]; //this will give us either 1 or 2 
       CenterPopup(id);
       LoadPopup(id)
   });    
});
var popupStatus = 0;
function CenterPopup(itemId)
{
  var item=$("#popupContact"+itemId);
  var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var popupHeight = item.height();
  var popupWidth = item.width();

  item.css({"position": "absolute",
      "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,
      "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
   });   
  $("#backgroundPopup"+itemId).css({
     "height": windowHeight
  });

}

function LoadPopup(itemId)
{     
 if(popupStatus==0){
    var item=$("#backgroundPopup"+itemId)
    item.css({"opacity": "0.7" });
    item.fadeIn("slow");
    $("#popupContact"+itemId).fadeIn("slow");
    popupStatus = 1;
  }
}
```

Working demo  http://jsfiddle.net/3FbbC/7/

This should work for the layout and javascript code you mentioned. But I seriously don't understand why you need 2 div's for same purpose (popContact1 & poupContact2). Since i am not sure abt your whole page objective, i am not able to tell you a better pattern.

Comment: thanks Shyju, i will give it a shot, the `popContact1 & poupContact2` should be only one div and what i am doing is that just displaying some text inside that div.

Comment: you code does not work when i click i dont get anything, i try to debugging but it never come where the document.ready... and yes i have a jquery ref on the page.... have you test your code?

Comment: @AbuHamzah: My bad, I wrote code like writing C#. Now fixed it. Check the working demo link i added in my updated answer. It is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to execute a similar function from the click event of different elements, you can define a single function, and then reuse it:

```
var myPopupFn = function($this){
  //do something to the element that is passed in
  $this.css({/* etc */});
}

$("#button1").click(function(){
   myPopupFn($(this));
});

$("#button2").click(function(){
   myPopupFn($(this));
});
```

Comment: Probably `$('#button1, #button2').click(function () {...});` looks better.

Comment: yeah, true, trying to keep it simple-

Answer (score 1):

If you have everything same except for the name difference, then use class selector instead of ID selector.

```
<a class="myLink" id="Link1" >Link1</a>
<a class="myLink" id="Link2" >Link1</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
   $('.myLink').click (function (e) {            
       $(this).css(/*{...}*/);
       //... Your code
       return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in a situation like this is create a function that simply takes two arguments (your IDs).

```
function whatever(id1, id2) {
    $("#"+id1).css({ "opacity": "0.7"}).fadeIn("slow");
    $("#"+id2).fadeIn("slow");
}
```

Then use:

```
whatever("backgroundPopup1", "popupContact1");
whatever("backgroundPopup2", "popupContact2");
```

This makes it more re-usable and increases robustness.

Comment: Yea, the code snippet is not reusable at all, what if you had a 3rd? You really want to copy/paste? Create methods to do the css and fadein for you, and just pass in the id's.  Also, you should not be using so much css, simply apply classes to your elements.